# Angular promises in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I've got loop function with promises:

```
for (var a in $scope.atrakcje) {
  if ($scope.atrakcje[a].x && $scope.atrakcje[a].y) {
    App.countDistance($scope.atrakcje[a].x, $scope.atrakcje[a].y).then(function(km) {
      $scope.atrakcje[a].distance = km;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem with this loop is that all km values are assigned to the last $scope.atrakcje element.
It should assign the first promise to the first element, the second to the second and so on.
How to do it?

Comment: This solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var a in $scope.atrakcje) {
  if ($scope.atrakcje[a].x && $scope.atrakcje[a].y) {
    (function(index) {
      App.countDistance($scope.atrakcje[index].x, $scope.atrakcje[index].y).then(function(km) {
        $scope.atrakcje[index].distance = km;
      });
    })(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `then` function is called after the `for` loop is finished, which means that when the promise is resolved, the `a` variable will contain the last key from $scope.atrakcje. Create a closure around it to capture the value of the key, something like:

```
Object.keys($scope.atrakcje).forEach(function(a) {
  if ($scope.atrakcje[a].x && $scope.atrakcje[a].y) {
    App.countDistance($scope.atrakcje[a].x, $scope.atrakcje[a].y).then(function(km) {
      $scope.atrakcje[a].distance = km;
    });
  }
});
```